# How to prioritize Newtonsoft's object reference resolution before type inheritance when deserializing in C#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I need object inheritance (using [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonInheritanceConverter), "_type")]) and object reference (using JsonSerializerSetting.TypeNameHandling = Auto) at the same time. Serialization works fine, but deserialization ends with exception.

Simplified Example:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonInheritanceConverter), "_type")]
    [KnownType(typeof(BaseClass))]
    [KnownType(typeof(DerivedClass))]
public class BaseClass{public List<BaseClass> Ancestors{get;set;}}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass{public string Name{get;set;}}
```

After Serialization it looks like:

```
{
  [
    {
      "$id": "1",
      "Ancestors": [],
      "_type": "BaseClass"
    },
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "Name": "A",
      "Ancestors": [{ "$ref": "1"}],
      "_type": "DerivedClass"
    }
  ]
}
```

During deserialization TraceWriter notifies:

> ...
> InvalidOperationException while 'Error deserializing System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[BaseClass]. Could not find subtype of 'BaseClass' with discriminator ''. Path 'Ancestors[0]'.': Could not find subtype of 'BaseClass' with discriminator ''.    at NJsonSchema.Converters.JsonInheritanceConverter.GetDiscriminatorType(JObject jObject, Type objectType, String discriminatorValue)
> <

Instead of resolving "$ref" = "1" first (see below: "Ancestors": [{ "$ref": "1"}]), it searches for my "_type": "BaseClass" first, which doesn't exist for a reference. In my opinion $ref should have precedence over _type.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It looks like your `JsonInheritanceConverter` is from external library, why don't you use `TypeNameHandling` setting out of the box?

Comment: It's right: JsonInheritanceConverter is only available in Json.NET. That was the only implementation that I could find. And it worked perfectly last year...
But: yes you remind me that this is not the proper way. I just didn't find a better OO-solution for Newtonsoft. And I cannot yet convert to Json.NET, because REST services will crash on converting my data for the REST response bc of the reference complexity in my data. What I found today: https://github.com/manuc66/JsonSubTypes. I will try this. If it works, I can clean the mix of Newtonsoft + Json.NET.
Thanx

Comment: What is `JsonInheritanceConverter`?  Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: Json.NET and Newtonsoft Json are same things, maybe you mean System.Net.Json?